# Calling an object attribute in IF statement condition

Tags: javascript, object, conditional-statements

I need to add a second person with an age less than 16 for my else statement to return it's string. How would I add this?

```
function canDrive(name, age) {
    var person = {
    name: "Stefano",
    age: 24,
    };

    if (person.age => 16) {
        return name + " is old enough to drive.";
    }
    else {
        return name + " is not old enough to drive.";
    }
}
```

Comment: `person.age` ....

Comment: if (person.age >= 16)

Comment: `person` is an object. try `if(person.age >= 16)`

Comment: I tried that yesterday and I still couldn't get it to work.

Comment: [Accessing objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) is the very basic level task. Notice also, that [`=>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) is not what you think it is ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change the if statement comparison like this `>=`.
2. And pass the only numbers for age, not a string that means no need to add `''` for age.
3. You are already passing a variable via a function.so no need add person object

```js
function canDrive(name, age) {
  if (age >= 16) {
    return name + " is old enough to drive.";
  } else {
    return name + " is not old enough to drive.";
  }
}

console.log(canDrive('ram',12))
console.log(canDrive('vj',22))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get age from person.age not only person. Here person is the object not variable

```
if(person.age >= 16) { } else { }
```

Comment: @Galwayshannon `=>` is not a [relational operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Relational_operators) ...